# Retroft GET Request Call

Tags: android, get, retrofit

There are a lot of examples but I didn't find what I really wanted (didn't get it) so if anyone would like to help it would be appreciated.

using post I know we do the following:

```
@POST("/SearchFor")
    @FormUrlEncoded
    void SearchFor(@Field("QueryID")String  QueryID,@Field("ElementID")String  ElementID,@Field("Language")String  Language, Callback<Response> cb);
```

Then implement on success and on failure.

now on GET:

The URL I want as an output is :

```
 URL+=BASE_URL+"?QueryID="+ID+"&ElementID=where%20"+INPUTFLDDBNAME+"%20like'%25"+Value+"%25'&Language="+interfacelang+"";
```

ID,INPUTFLDDBNAME,interfacelang will be replaced by strings

So I did the following:

```
 @GET("/QueryID={QueryID}&ElementID=where%20{ElementID}%20like'%25{Value}%25'&Language={Language}")
    void SearchFor(@Path("QueryID")String  QueryID,@Path("ElementID")String  ElementID,@Path("Value")String  Value,@Path("Language")String  Language, Callback<Response> cb);
```

but obviously it didn't work and got the following error:

```
No Retrofit annotation found. (parameter #1)
```

this is how im calling it

```
Retrofit Retrofit=new Retrofit();
                    RestAPI PushNotificationWebService=Retrofit.SetRestAdapter("BASE_URL");
                    PushNotificationWebService.SearchFor(ID,fields.get(0).getText().toString(),INPUTFLDDBNAME,interfacelang,new Callback<Response>() {
                        @Override
                        public void success(Response response, Response response2) {
...
```

Please someone guide me it would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `@Query()` to add the query params to your base URL

```
@GET("/SearchFor")
void SearchFor(@Query("QueryID") String QueryID, @Query("ElementID") String ElementID,@Query("Language") String Language, Callback<Response> cb)
```

Then use something along the lines of:

```
String element = URLEncoder.encode(String.format("where %s like'%%%s%%'", element_id, value));
PushNotificationWebService.SearchFor(ID, element, ...)
```

Comment: it worked, but the url is sending wrong..the spaces are replaced with + and should be replaced with %20 and when replacing them to %20, the URL is becoming %20%20  (twice)

Comment: Try using this `@Query(value="QueryID", encodeValue=true)`